# How to create a custom textbox with a label and value

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, labels, data-tables, textbox

I am not a designer but I am dealing with a task to implement a functionality. 
I have to develop a working UI where a user can enter values into text-boxes inside a grid. While entering these values the user should have a reference value, which is different for each text-box in the grid. I therefore want to design a text-box where the user sees the reference value while entering the values. Can anyone suggest a good design to solve this problem?

What I have thought of is having a custom text-box with an uneditable label on the top left of the text-box, while the other area of the text-box is editable (to enter the value).

[image]

So as seen in the image above, the top left is where I will show the value to be referred, while the white space is a text-box where the user can enter the value.

Below is another image with what I want to finally achieve:

[image]

If my proposed solution is a good one then how do I implement it? Are there other solutions anyone can suggest?

Comment: How many states do the grid boxes have?

Comment: just one state. the reference value is just to refer which is fixed and it will not change , it will come from backend. later on I am also looking for the user to enter a reason if there is a difference between the actual value entered and the referenced value. This specific functionality will be across all text boxes in the grid with validation. Any other solution better then one I have thought of is most welcomed..

Comment: How many of these boxes would someone need to complete? Is the previou values always a small number with a decimal point?

Comment: one box per grid cell is required to complete.  The previous values will always be less than 10 and in decimal upto 1 decimal place i.e 0.0 to 9.9

Comment: I have added a new image what I want to achieve

Comment: why do the previous values matter?

Answer (score 6):

I find the approach you present quite clear. I would simply organise the values without adding oblique lines and use some opacity to differentiate the elements.

[image]

In the image one of the fields is hovered, so it's buttons *edit field* and *edit comment* appear, which would open a [simple dialog](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-interaction):

[image]

Normally the edit icon wouldn't be necessary as it is the only action. But in your case you have an extra action which is *add a comment*. These could be the possible interactions.

1. *Click* in empty Field T (there are no edit/comment icons)
2. Add value in Simple Dialog from Field T
3. *Enter*
4. Add comment in Simple Dialog from Field T
5. *Enter*

Finished. Edit field:

1. *Click* in Field T (not in edit or comment icon)
2. Edit value in Simple Dialog from Field T
3. *Tab*
4. Edit comment in Simple Dialog from Field T
5. *Tab*
6. Edit value in Simple Dialog from Field U
7. *Tab*
8. Edit comment in Simple Dialog from Field U

etc.

Depending on the situation if the values will be changed without the need to change the comment, you could skip the comment edit (4+5) in the above workflow.

Comment: that's a good option, but for mass update , the user experience will slow down as textboxes are by default editable and can be navigated easily and continuously by the TAB key.

Comment: @Chetan You can edit the value with the same method, tab opens the small dialog (like [this image](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_10/assets/0B3mOPoJlxiFhZHhJSVhoT2JuTkE/components_datatables_interaction_editing2.png))

Answer (score 0):

### Use color coding

[image: color coding of data table cells]

Color coding differences between reference and actual values could help users quickly locate problematic fields. You can use colors or simply highlight a table cell with grey color.

---

**Update:**

> when there is a mismatch between actual and reference value a
>   reason should be entered

To put descriptive information in the intended field you could use a **Popover**. They are great for quick edits and entries. An input field is presented in-context to the related data so users don’t lose orientation in the data table.

[image: popover input field in a data table]

Then the entered description could be displayed as a **[tooltip](https://material.io/guidelines/components/tooltips.html#tooltips-usage)**. When you want to check why a particular cell has a mismatch user just hovers over it and reads the description. This way a lot of screen space is saved.

Comment: sounds good , but values have to be explicitly visualized and if there is a difference then some corner of textbox with expanding some panel to enter the reason? any suggestions?

Comment: If I understood correctly when there is a mismatch between actual and reference value you should enter a reason?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

You can have a textbox and reference value as a  placeholder text and when the user clicks on the textbox the old value disappears and he can enter the new value. For example : Search Box

Answer (score 0):

Like all elements of a UI’s design, consistency with label positioning helps users and minimizes errors. This means it’s best if you can use the same approach in this form as in the other forms.

I suppose you will use an inline editing for this table (datatable probably) and you will have an input in every cell with the reference value as a label.

As development method, the label shouldn't have an absolute position necessarily. You can have a smaller height for the input than the cell and position the label before.

The advantages of having the label on the top of the input are:

- the user may be able to see the label and the field within one glance;
- allows for different label lengths and the width is bigger than if is in the corner;
- easy to implement.